# How to set fragment id when using swipe tabs and ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I followed the video at slidenerd to create swipe tabs using fragments.
I basically implemented a pagerAdapter:

```
class pagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter
{

    public pagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        if (arg0 == 0)
            fragment = new fragmentA();
        if (arg0 == 1)
            fragment = new fragmentB();
        if (arg0 == 2)
            fragment = new fragmentC();
        if (arg0 == 3)
            fragment = new fragmentD();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 4;
    }

}
```

And this works great so far.
Now I wish to be able to send information from one fragment to the other trough the activity.
What I did was creating a communicator interface which both activity and fragments implement.

```
public interface Communicator {
    public void Send(int from, int to, Object object);
    public void Receive(int id, Object object);
}
```

If fragmentA wishes to send fragmentB a message, I just use `Send(a's id, b's id, someData)`
the activity handles the message and uses fragmentManager to deliver the message to b:

```
public void Send(int from, int to, Object object) {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Communicator comm = (Communicator) fm.findFragmentById(...);
    if (comm != null)
        comm.Receive(from, object);
}
```

This is exactly where Im stuck. I need to get a pointer to my fragment, but dont know how to give it an id..the viewPager is a bit confusing me.

Comment: The fragmentStatePagerAdapter can shut down fragments when it needs to and so may not be available for sending messages to.

Comment: @Kuffs thanks for noticing. Do you mean, also as java object, or just as a view?

Comment: If it needs to, it will shut down the fragment until it is needed again in which case it will start it up again. If you need your fragments to exist until YOU decide to get rid of them, you need a FragmentPagerAdapter.

Comment: Hey how did you end up setting the id?, can you show what you did I am trying to get the activity to just talk to one fragment...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the reference of fragment from adapter it-self:

```
public void Send(int from, int to, Object object) {

    Communicator comm = pagerAdapter.getItem(to);
    if (comm != null)
        comm.Receive(from, object);
}
```

Here to and from should be index of the fragments inside adapter.

Comment: I see. thanks. But Im not sure if its 100% good for me as one of the fragments is being replaced during user activity. i.e tab0 is the search fragment, where the search operation replaces the fragment in tab0 to the results fragment, and then I'd like to send a message from search fragment to results fragment. I cant use the pagerAdapter as it will send the message to itself

Comment: you can just keep the reference to the result and search fragments while replacing and just call send on the object of search

Comment: Isnt there any other way to get pointer/set id of fragment to fragments other than by the viewPager?

Comment: I don't think it is possible for dynamically created fragments.

Comment: About your answer, since the mechanism of tabs calls getItem only when the fragment has to be created for the first time, wont it cause bad behavior if I call it myself? Wont it just create a new fragment, instead of receiving the current one that already exists (either as a view or just a java object) ?

Comment: Yes it will create different object. For that you should create a list of fragments and initialize it in cinstructor of your afapter

Comment: Thank you. I modified my pagerAdapter to contain a predefined list of fragments. Then, instead of creating a new one in `getItem()`, I return an item from my list. This way, Im able to use it in order to get reference to my current fragments